# Can i get something from a list with multiple objects of a class?

Tags: c++, list, class

I have :

```
class Library
{
private:
list<Publication> L;
}
class Publication
{
protected:
string title;
string editor;
}

class Book:public Publication
{
private:
vector<string> Author;
}
```

When i insert a book on my list i lose the Authors? If not when i want to display one of the Publication from the list i want to also show the Author of the publication. How can i do that without modifying the structure of the list?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without changing the type of `L`. It's a `list<Publication>` - it stores `Publication`s, not `Book`s. If you push a `Book` into it, it will be sliced, leaving you with only the `Publication` part.

If you want to store `Publication`s polymorphically, you'll need to use pointers or references. I recommend using one of the following:

```
// When the Library has sole-ownership of a dynamically allocated Publication:
std::list<std::unique_ptr<Publication>> L;
// When the Library has shared-ownership of a dynamically allocated Publication:
std::list<std::shared_ptr<Publication>> L;
// When the Library wants a reference to a Publication:
std::list<std::reference_wrapper<Publication>> L;
```

If for any reason you can't use any of these, you can of course store raw pointers in `L`.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing `Publication` objects, so when you attempt to store `Books`, you get [*object slicing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). The solution would be to store [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) to `Publications`. For example,

```
#include <memory>
class Library
{
private:
  std::list<std::unique_ptr<Publication>> L;
};
```